# XSD maxOccurs="unbounded"

Tags: xml, xsd

I have generated an XSD file from an XML snippet using `xsd.exe /out`

What its done is created `maxOccurs="unbounded"` properties for certain elements.

If I only want the element to appear once, and not be a collection do I set the maxOccurs like this?

> maxOccurs="1"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes.  Of course, keep in mind that maxOccurs is really maximum occurances - there can still be zero.  If you want there to always be one, you'll need minOccurs="1" as well.

Comment: `maxOccurs="1" and minOccurs="1"` are default if these attributes aren't specified.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's how it's done.

`maxOccurs` limits the maximum number of repetitions of a given element that can appear.

Similarly, `minOccurs` limits the minimum number of repetitions.

They're called occurrence indicators. You can [read more about them at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp).

Comment: So this means that if I set maxOccurs="1", when I generate the C# class, these properties wont become collections?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one, but probably. If you want to know that you should include it in your question.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp says that:
"The default value for both maxOccurs and minOccurs is 1!"

Comment: yeah. those default values arent shown where they belong-- http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp and are hidden till that p. you've given!

Comment: Updated links are https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp