# XML schema for no sequence and multiple occurs

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd

1. I need to create a schema for validate a XML file.
2. The elements inside `Mother` tag can be `Son` or `Daughter`
3. `Son` or `Daughter` element do not have any sequence.
4. `Son` cannot me multiple element (Only one son).
5. But `Daughter` can be multiple (Multiple daughters).

So my question is how to write a XML schema for this. This is what I wrote. Instead of `<xsd:all>` I tried `<xsd:sequence>` and `<xsd:choice>` also. But I couldn't figure out how to overcome this.

```
<xsd:complexType name="Mother">     
 <xsd:all>
  <xsd:element name="Son" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <xsd:element name="Daughter" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
 </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

-------------------------------These are the correct XML files--------------------------------

### **With Multiple daughters**

```
<Mother>
<Son>Jhon</Son>
<Daughter>Rose</Daughter>
<Daughter>Ann</Daughter>
</Mother>
```

### With different sequence

```
<Mother>
<Daughter>Rose</Daughter>
<Son>Jhon</Son>
<Daughter>Ann</Daughter>
</Mother>
```

### Without Son or Without Daughter or Without both

```
<Mother>
<Daughter>Rose</Daughter>
</Mother>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSD Question maxOccurs="unbounded"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165845/xsd-question-maxoccurs-unbounded)

Comment: Marc B : you are wrong this time. This is not duplicate. Here nothing to do with `maxOccurs=“unbounded”`. because `xtd:all` cannot use with it.

Comment: who marked my question as `This question may already have an answer here`. did you read the question before do it? =)

Comment: It would help greatly if you gave examples of valid and invalid instance documents. This would be especially useful since your English is limited and not 100% clear.

Comment: Michael Kay: thank you for the comment and sorry for the poor English. I eddied the question for more details. Hope it clears the question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you could do it as a `sequence` of zero or more `Daughter` elements, followed by zero or one `Son` and then another zero or more `Daughter`s

```
<xsd:complexType name="Mother">     
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="Daughter" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xsd:element name="Son" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <xsd:element name="Daughter" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

If the element content were more complex than just a string I'd be inclined to declare separate top level elements and reference them using `<xsd:element ref="Daughter" minOccurs=....`

Comment: Grate and this works fine. Could you give me some clue (Like how parser works in this), what is the logic behind this and how did you think to get this answer. Because I'm quit wonder why it needs to add two element for same name (It never came to my mind =)).